# Red5 server is not running on different location (on IP)

Tags: red5

i have installed red5 on my server.its running fine on my IP but when i open red5 link (http://myhost:5080) on different IP (or on client side )its not working.
please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open 5080 port in your Firewall.